# Visual studio community 2019 version 16.6.2 is missing the build tab in the menu any way to fix it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm using it with unity in unity editor I did double click on a csharp script and it opened the visual studio. Could be the problem is that it's the regular visual studio and not the unity visual studio that I downloaded and installed ?

The Start Debugging is grayed out I can make only Attach but sure what is going on.

No build menu options nothing.

and before I saw the solution window and there was only the solution properties there not the project properties.

[image: debugging is disabled]

[image: Only attach]

Comment: have you installed any extension in visual studio like PostSharp, if yes then uninstall or reinstall

Comment: Try Menu: `Tools => Import and Export Settings => Reset All Settings` I hope this helps.

Comment: Do you have the [`Visual Studio Tools For Unity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/cross-platform/getting-started-with-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?view=vs-2019) installed for your `Visual Studio` installation? (Be careful to uncheck the Unity installation itself if you don't need it ;) )

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue
Close the project and open its location in folders and then right click on it and click on -Open with - Visual Studio 2019

It resolved my issue.